# Access post body without bodyparser

Tags: express, http, websocket

I am trying to send a bas64 encoded image to my express server and parse it there to save it to disk. Id like to implement this with a simple http post request but couldn't get it to work. My first implementation utilized a websocket server and worked well:

Client:

```
const object = JSON.stringify({
    action: "add_image",
    data: dataUrl,
})
ws.send(object)
```

Server:

```
ws.on("message", (message) => {

    const req = JSON.parse(message);

    fs.writeFile(
        "path/to/file.png",
        data.split(";base64,").pop(),
        { encoding: "base64" },
        (err) => err && console.log(err)
    )
}
```

This is my trying to get the same result with an http request.

Client:

```
const object = JSON.stringify({
    action: "add_image",
    data: dataUrl,
})
fetch("http://localhost:3001/add_image", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: new Headers({
        Origin: window.origin,
        Accept: "image/png",
        "Content-Type": "image/png",
    }),
    mode: "cors",
    body: object,
})
```

Server:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post("/add_image", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

Unfortunately, req.body always logs an empty object.

I am not quite sure what I am lacking. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in [this](https://itnext.io/how-to-handle-the-post-request-body-in-node-js-without-using-a-framework-cd2038b93190) article. I needed to combine all individual chunks of the request and then use the data once the process is complete.

```
app.post("/add_image", function (req, res) {

    let body = '';

    req.on('data', chunk => {
        body += chunk.toString();
    });

    req.on('end', () => {
        console.log(JSON.parse(body));
        res.end('ok');
    });

});
```